# Need to add constraint on the basis of another column

Tags: mysql

We need to add a foreign key constraint on the basis of another column. As you can see in the screenshot below, we have columns `refer_id` and `reference_type`. We need to add a constraint on the column `refer_id` based on the value contained in column `reference_type`. We will always have two values of data type `ENUM`: `Manual` or `User`.

If `reference_type` has a value of `Manual`, we need to add a foreign key to the `refer_id` column on table `reference_detail` whose primary key column is `id`.  If `reference_type` has a value of `User`, then we need to add a foreign key to the `refer_id` column on table `users` whose primary key is `id`.

Please help me how to add constraints on the basis of these conditions.

Please see table structure in below **screenshot**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Add some code, what have you done so far.

Comment: I am trying to do it in phpmyadmin

Comment: No can do, You can only reference one table in a foreign key constraint. You might consider using a trigger,

Answer (score 0):

You can't add conditional foreign key(At least not in MySQL). A foreign key on the table can only reference a single primary column, and even if you can(in some RDBMS) it is considered a bad practice.

What you can do is that, you can create two child tables which references each parent table reference_detail(ENUM:Manual) and users(ENUM:Users).

It will be more clearer than your approach and easier to query. This is what I can make out of the database structure you have described.

Hope this helps.